# Measure distance between teeth using Machine Learning

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, cnn, class-imbalance

I'm a newbie in ML and I have a problem I am stuck on.

I want to train a ML model to recognize dental diagnosis based on photos and x-rays of the patient. Specifically right now, I want to find a way to measure the [overbite](https://d1l9wtg77iuzz5.cloudfront.net/assets/5501/248215/original.svg?1542210077). It is defined as

> The length on the bottom tooth that is covered by the top tooth

So if my top tooth slightly covers the bottom one, the overbite will be low. Here's an example of a small [1-2mm overbite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30P61.jpg) and another of a large [5-7mm overbite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSd1h.jpg).

A typical x-ray might look like this:

[image]

You can see the ruler on the top right as a reference object to measure the gap between the top frontal jaw vs. bottom jaw. In this case, the overbite is measured to be `5-7mm`.

In my dataset I have about 7,000 x-rays where the overbite is one of seven values:

```
(-3)mm+ | 0-(-2)mm | 1-2mm | 3-4mm | 5-7mm | 8mm+ | Normal
```

Keep in mind my classes are not balanced.

```
(-3)mm+       99
0-(-2)mm     515
1-2mm       2376
3-4mm       3059
5-7mm        846
8mm+           8
Normal        36
```

How can I train an ML model to find the distance better? Things I have tried:

- Increase how much data I use. (Went from 900 -> 3,800 -> 7,000)
- Using a simple CNN (Val accuracy 46%)
- Tweak the layers setup and hyper-parameters (No difference)
- Apply `class_weights`
- Fine-tuning a pre-trained `ResNet50` model (Val accuracy 51%)

### EDIT:

To add context my images are `(512,512,3)` and this is my latest architecture:

```
OG_IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, color_channels)
input_shape = (None,) + OG_IMG_SHAPE
num_classes = len(class_names)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=OG_IMG_SHAPE)
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = resize_and_rescale(x)
x = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(x)
x = resnet50_base_model(x, training=False)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy', 'mse'])

model.build(OG_IMG_SHAPE)
model.summary()
```

Comment: If you weight the classes to counter class imbalance, it is normal that the accuracy will decrease. But the point is that the under-represented classes will be classified better. Also, since you have little data, I would suggest data augmentation for the under-represented classes, such as 20crop, introducing noise like a gaussian blur, rotations, translations, etc. Maybe you can also make the task for the model easier by choosing a smaller part of the x-ray (you never mention how large your image is and whether it includes the whole head).

Comment: Hi, one potential way to improve accuracy is through data augmentation (i.e. artificially creating more data by transforming images [rotation, scaling, etc.])

Comment: @postnubilaphoebus The original image is 512x512 and does indeed include the whole head.

Comment: @shepan6 The TF docs recommends embedding the `data_augmentation` layers directly into the model which is what I did. Are you suggesting doing that to the Dataset directly?

Comment: Yes, a suggestion would be to do this to the dataset directly. It depends on how much control over the distortions/transformations you have in the data augmentation layers.

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure why you need to approach this as a classification problem. Because the images seem like they will be so consistent, I think I would try to break this down into very interpretable steps. If you were doing this manually the steps would be something like this:

- **Find the ruler and perform some calibration**. In other words: determine how many mm a pixel is. If the ruler is consistently in the exact same position, this doesn't require any sort of neural network. Some basic image segmentation or pattern recognition technique should work. If not it might be trickier.
- **Find the tip of the top tooth.**. You would need to be able to segment that front tooth properly and then find the tip. The first part could benefit from NNs but finding the tip should be easy if your segmentation is good. It's sharp and points down. So it should be easily detected by a corner detection algorithm but you might get away by picking the lowest pixel of that tooth.
- **Find the tip of the bottom tooth**. Same thing as for top tooth.
- **Measure the distance between the two tips** or whatever exact definition people use for overbite. Actually, I would definitely start by completely clarifying that point to make sure the approach makes sense.

I think I would prefer this approach over a Classifier because it is a lot more modular and if you need to adapt it to other measurements or if the reference ruler changes you can just change one part of the system. Also, I would expect it to be a lot more robust since you can easily evaluate each step and create some visualization that demonstrates the results in a clear way. Granted, you would need to label the dataset to be able to do this, which is pretty tedious but I think it is worth it.

This seems fun. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. By labeling the dataset, are you talking about annotating the image with bounding boxes?

Comment: To your first point, the ruler is usually on the top right but the position is not exact

Comment: Is the ruler always the same shape or are there different kinds of rulers too?

And yes, if you want to be able to detect these rulers using a supervised learning approach, you would need to have a labeled dataset where you know *where* they are so a mask of the exact pixels would probably give you the best results. If the ruler's shape is very similar across images, you could use some feature detector and simple filtering but otherwise, you would need to train or fine-tune a model.

Comment: I added some context about the definition of an "overbite". It is not the distance from the top tooth to the bottom tooth.

Comment: Ok good! most of the comments I made still apply, only the last step needs to be modified: You can get a vector from the teeth tips and project that on some axis. But you still need to nail down the way a human would actually measure this distance to understand which axis you'll use: the vertical axis of the image, the axis perpendicular to the plane formed by the teeth contact, bottom tooth..?

Answer (score 1):

Your target is **ordinal** and as it is, your loss function does not use that. I would give a try to architectures that output ordinal data, that might increase your performance a lot. These posts might help:

- [How to set up neural network to output ordinal data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140061/how-to-set-up-neural-network-to-output-ordinal-data)
- [Classification with ordered classes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222073/classification-with-ordered-classes)

You could, for example, try regression models (by taking the mean values of each category).

In addition to this, as said in comments, **data augmentation** will help and everything you can do in **preprocessing** that can focus on your problem (for example croping the image to keep only relevant data).

*Note*
If you use data augmentation on dataset, be careful to use augmented images in the same training/testing dataset to prevent leakage.